# I set up modal's height to be smaller but it takes full screen and doesn't show appropriatelly

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I am writing a simple chat app where a user can send a photo. Once a user click on a message with a photo, it is been rendered inside `ImageViewer`. Then I have the option to saved the photo. Once the photo is saved, I want to display modal with "you saved your photo" or something like this. So far so good. BUT, the modal with the informative message appears to take full screen instead of just one row message.  Here is my code:

```
return (
    <>
      
        <Modal
          animationType="slide"
          visible={showImageViewer && savedPhoto}
          onRequestClose={() => {
            setSavedPhoto(false);
          }}
        >
          <View style={styles.modalViewStyle}>
            <Text style={styles.modalTextStyle}>
              Please, dont take the whole screen
            </Text>
          </View>
        </Modal>
    </>
  );
```

My imports:

```
import ImageViewer from "react-native-image-zoom-viewer";
import { GiftedChat } from "react-native-gifted-chat";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  Image,
  Modal,
  TouchableOpacity,
  StyleSheet,
} from "react-native";
```

My styling:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  image: {
    width: 150,
    height: 100,
    borderRadius: 13,
    margin: 3,
    resizeMode: "cover",
  },
  modalViewStyle: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    flexDirection: "row",
    borderWidth: 3,
    borderColor: "red",
    height: 40,
    flex: 1 / 10,
  },
  modalTextStyle: {
    fontWeight: "bold",
    color: "green",
    fontSize: 15,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the modal background to transparent and style the child view like this

```
<Modal transparent={true}
   visible={this.state.isVisible}
   onRequestClose={this.closeModal}>
<View style={{
      flex: 1,
      flexDirection: 'column',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center'}}>
<View style={{
        width: 300,
        height: 300}}>
  // you modal content here
</View>
```

Comment: I already googled few similar questions, all of them saying Modal doesn't have a style property and that the styling should go to the child element

Comment: you have to make the modal transparent in this case, let me update the answer according to that

Comment: Updated, try this one, it should work now